# Happy to hear that!/ Great to hear that!/ Glad to hear that!

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-request, phrases

I'd like to express (via text message) that **I'm happy/glad** to hear that you'd like to work with us as a volunteer. I omitted the rest of the sentence (about volunteering work) because I have mentioned this before. Here's the scenario:

> A: Hi, would you be interested in working as a volunteer at [name of the organization]?
>
> B: Yeah, sure! I think it's just what I need right now.
>
> A: Happy to hear that!

Is the phrase "Happy to hear that" used by native speakers?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are asking for? Another word for glad/happy?

Comment: "I'm happy to hear that" / "I'm glad to hear that" / "That's great to hear" — none of these is overly formal for just a casual conversation. None is particularly _informal,_ either; they're just normal. (To my ear, "glad" is slightly more informal than the other two.) If you want to sound _particularly_ informal, you could say something like "That's awesome." But if you're just trying to avoid sounding formal/stuffy, those three are just fine.

Comment: @Element115 I'm asking if this phrase "Happy to hear that" is used by native speakers, and I was looking for an informal version.

Comment: @spoko Is there any difference between "Happy to hear that" and "I'm happy to hear that"?

Comment: "Happy to hear that" is less formal. Any time there are words which are only implied, rather than stated, it's probably going to be less formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more informal way of showing your emotion might be saying

> Fantastic!
>   That's great!

In your context, where you're asking someone to volunteer for you, saying

> I'm happy to hear that.

Could sound a bit stand-offish if not delivered with the right intonation.

Comment: What about in writing? I should have mentioned that earlier... Can I use the emoji icons or maybe punctuation marks to soften this sentence "I'm happy to hear that.", or maybe the only way is to change it to "Happy to hear that!"?

Comment: Emojis are good for messaging, but never in a formal setting.